# Orchard CMS or Other Calendar

Tags: calendar, orchardcms, fullcalendar-3

I am working on a site and we need a calendar exactly like on this page: http://www.houseofblues.com/concert-events

The site seems developed in Orchard CMS, do you know which type of plugin, module they are using for calendar? From where we can get this calendar ?

Comment: Actually it is not a calendar.  Nor a module. It is a list of content items - events in this case, with custom shape.

Comment: Same thing on this site: https://les-lilas.com/events. No need for a special module. The built-in content type system is more than enough. The only thing custom is a custom template in the theme, but only because projection layouts can become a little harder to manage above a certain complexity.

Comment: Thanks guys, can we get something similar to  http://www.houseofblues.com/concert-events in Wordpress? Any plugin that gives very close layout to this?